# Suppress re-frame re-render

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

Is it possible to suppress a re-render? Suppose I dispatch handler `[:a]` and handler `[:b]` on state `db-0`. Such that:

```
db-0 -> [:a] -> db-1 -> [:b] -> db-0
```

The end state is the same but two re-renders are made. I do not wish for a re-render of the intermediary state `db-1`. A re-render, if necessary, should only happen after both `[:a]` and `[:b]` have both been applied.

Comment: Probably you should write an event that merges a and b into one.

Answer (score 1):

### Background

If a `dispatch` causes a change to `app-db`, an animation frame will be "scheduled" to handle any necessary re-rendering. As a result, that re-rendering will occur about 16ms later.

If, in the meantime, another `dispatch` happens, then its changes to `app-db` will also be handled in the already-scheduled, upcoming animation frame.

By the time the AF rolls around, the changes for both `dispatched` events will be manifest in `app-db`.

### Your Scenario

So, as you can see, the dispatch of `[:a]` will cause an AF to be scheduled, however before it is run, your `dispatch` of `[:b]` will further change `app-db` back to its original state.

When later the AF runs, all the layer 2 subscriptions will run, all of them, because `app-db` was changed (in some way as yet unknown) BUT because previous values will `=` new values, the signal graph propagation will be pruned, and no re-renders will ultimately run.

Comment: To throw a wrench into things, suppose `[:a]` and `[:b]` are `http-xhrio` events that take longer than 16ms. What now?

Comment: deadghost: are they independent request or dependent and hence sequential?

Comment: @deadghost  if they are both purely http-xhrio requests, there will be no change to `app-db` and no rerender.  `app-db` has to change for their to (potentially) be re-renders.